# can I make docker image via dockerTools.buildImage and configure it with nixos configuration

Tags: docker, nix, nixos

I think the biggest drawback of `dockerTools.buildImage` is that I have to configure all low-level stuff myself.

Can I make docker image and provision its content using `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`- like configuration?

For example: make image with nginx using [this](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/cb11bf73a511819ee36c4bddb97573aacda0b161/nixos/tests/nghttpx.nix#L8-L21) configuration.

Comment: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/36769 related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question is stupid, container can't have systemd, so nixos configuration doesn't make sense.

**Edit**: waiting for nixos modules to support docker

Comment: No, your question is not stupid. It only has an unsatisfactory answer, at the moment. You may be interested in https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/26067 for some ideas.

Comment: nix is going to support docker backend. Can't even imagine how this will work

Comment: Technically that'd be NixOS instead of Nix. Hint: systemd is just a normal NixOS module. It's just that a lot of other modules define configuration for it.